# Multi dimensional array containing array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Trough my ios first app developpement i have to re-order an array containing dictionaires, parsed from a xml document, the purpose of re-ordering it is to send it to a function that build a collapsible, so it need a childCell index and a parentCell Index to print the strings of each child then pass to another parent. The problem is here : i'am able to fill my big array containing arrays of dictionaries, then i that array and do a loop to fill the childArray to contain multiple dictionaries, then i add this child array to my parent array, every thing seem to run but it gives me an empty array at the end. i put my code to show you how i tried to do this :

stories is the NSArray of dictionaries, childArray is the Array that should contain the dictionaries of stories, and parentArray is the Array that contains it all.
If someone who already did that can explain me were it goes wrong please it would be very much appreciated.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)orderChildsAndParents:(NSMutableArray *)fromArray
{
    int varial = 0;
    int catIndex = 0;

    NSMutableArray *parentArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    while(varial < [stories count])
    {
        NSString* cleanedString = [[[[stories objectAtIndex:varial] objectForKey:@"category"] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
                                   componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        if ([cleanedString isEqualToString:[category objectAtIndex:catIndex] ])
        {
            if (!childArray || !childArray.count)
            childArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            [childArray addObject:[stories objectAtIndex:varial]];
            varial++;
        }
        else{
            [parentArray addObject:childArray];
            [childArray removeAllObjects];
            catIndex++;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", parentArray);
    return parentArray;
}

- (NSString *) labelForCellAtChildIndex:(NSInteger) childIndex withinParentCellIndex:(NSInteger) parentIndex {

    NSMutableArray *orderedArray = [self orderChildsAndParents:stories];
    NSLog(@"format string %@",  [[[orderedArray objectAtIndex:parentIndex] objectAtIndex:childIndex] objectForKey:@"name"]); // empty :8
    return [[[orderedArray objectAtIndex:parentIndex] objectAtIndex:childIndex] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: Since the method's logic depends on many things that are external to the method, I suggest using the debugger or `NSLog` to determine which branches the code takes.

Comment: Yes i'm on the debugger, my parentArray fills right in the first go in the else statement, then in the second run int the else it goes empty, add the childArray but with no data in it :8, i must do something really wrong somewhere.

Comment: just asking but, can i choose the index where i add a new object like addObjectAtIndex (that doesn't exist) ??

Comment: the debugger just show me that when i removeAllObjects from childArray it removes them from parentArray, is there a way to add an object but as a copy not actually really add the object ??? Sorry i'm asking a lot of question but it's to clarify all this.

Comment: I suspect that what you need to do is create a new `childArray` when you're done filling the one you're giving to `parentArray` rather than removing its objects.

Comment: This: `if (!childArray || !childArray.count) childArray = [NSMutableArray array];` **leaks memory** if `childArray` is empty but not nil.

Comment: Yes SIR ! your idea was that little thing that i missed, that little word to unlock it, i set a Boolean and when i go in the else statement i set it to YES. So when i go in the if statement i check the BOOL if yes a re-creat an array as you said and don't erase it anymore. Works great, Thanks :D !